# Do we need to check if an unordered_set contains an element before trying to erase it?

Tags: c++, c++11

Say I have a set:

```
std::unordered_set<int> mints;
```

Then I do:

```
mints.erase(foo);
```

But mints doesn't contain foo! Is it guaranteed that nothing bad will happen, and that erase will simply just return 0 ?

Comment: Seems easier to just read the documentation. E.g. [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set/erase)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you get the overloaded `erase()` with `erase( const key_type& key )` and the key doesn't exist then nothing bad will happen, it'll be a no-op and `erase()` will return `0`.